# implement alpha for custom colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot a collection of patches using a custom colormap.  I have gotten this working fine, however I can't use alpha properly with my custom colormap.  As you can see in the images and attached code, the alpha is applied to the patches, but the colorbar still shows with alpha=1 making the map "wrong".  To check, I tested the with jet, and the colorbar reflects the proper alpha.  I am assuming something is missing in the way I defined my colorbar, but the documentation has not been helpful in figuring out what...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.rand(50,1)*500; y = np.random.rand(50,1)*500;
radius = np.random.rand(50,1)*50
patches = []
for i in range(len(radius)):
    circle = matplotlib.patches.Circle((x[i], y[i]), radius[i])
    patches.append(circle)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = 100*np.random.rand(len(patches))
p = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches)
p.set(array = colors, cmap = 'Spectral', alpha=0.5)
ax.add_collection(p)
plt.colorbar(p, alpha=0.5)
plt.xlim(0,500);plt.ylim(0,500);
plt.gca().set_aspect(1)
plt.show()

############
r = np.hstack((np.zeros(425),np.linspace(0,255,430), np.linspace(254,0,425)))
g = np.hstack((np.linspace(0,255,430), np.linspace(254,0,425), np.zeros(425)))
b = np.hstack((np.linspace(255,0,430), np.zeros(425),np.linspace(0,254,425)))
c = np.array([r,g,b]).T
mycm = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(c/255.0)
###########
x = np.random.rand(50,1)*500; y = np.random.rand(50,1)*500;
radius = np.random.rand(50,1)*50
patches = []
for i in range(len(radius)):
    circle = matplotlib.patches.Circle((x[i], y[i]), radius[i])
    patches.append(circle)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = 100*np.random.rand(len(patches))
p = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches)
p.set(array = colors, cmap = mycm, alpha=0.5)
ax.add_collection(p)
plt.colorbar(p, alpha=0.5)
plt.xlim(0,500);plt.ylim(0,500);
plt.gca().set_aspect(1)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot made using jet]
[image: plot made using my colormap]

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the first case picture, matplotlib adds small lines between the colors in the colorbar. Those lines come from the `pcolormesh` that is used to produce the colorbar. I have no idea why they are there, nor would I know how to get rid of them, but those lines are the reason for the problem of the alpha value not being shown correctly. 
As they appear a bit darker then the real color shown, it is clear that if one adds more and more lines to the colorbar, the complete colorbar will be composed of those lines and thus appear darker or less transparent.
This is exactly what is done in the second case, where a `ListedColormap` with 430+425+425 = 1280 values is used.

The solution would therefore be to **reduce the number of colors in the `ListedColormap`** to a value below 255. In the example code below I used 90.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
############
n= 30
r = np.hstack((np.zeros(n),np.linspace(0,255,n), np.linspace(254,0,n)))
g = np.hstack((np.linspace(0,255,n), np.linspace(254,0,n), np.zeros(n)))
b = np.hstack((np.linspace(255,0,n), np.zeros(n),np.linspace(0,254,n)))
c = np.array([r,g,b]).T
mycm = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(c/255.0)
###########
x = np.random.rand(50,1)*500; y = np.random.rand(50,1)*500;
radius = np.random.rand(50,1)*50
patches = []
for i in range(len(radius)):
    circle = matplotlib.patches.Circle((x[i], y[i]), radius[i])
    patches.append(circle)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = 100*np.random.rand(len(patches))
p = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches)
p.set(array = colors, cmap = mycm, alpha=0.5)
ax.add_collection(p)
plt.colorbar(p, alpha=0.5)
plt.xlim(0,500);plt.ylim(0,500);
plt.gca().set_aspect(1)
plt.savefig(__file__+".png")
plt.show()
```

[image]